# On a table of MySQL, can I designate the path of some file instead of data?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I'm trying to develop a web application using MySQL and PHP.

My web application shall enable users to check their business result through the web. To develop this functionality successfully, I will make a table that includes users' information by PDF format.

Technically, the row of the table is not data, just the path of the PDF file that exists somewhere in the file system.

Specifically, when a user logs on via the web, he can see the list of some information and an article of the list is linked to a PDF file. So when the user clicks the article, the MySQL server shall call the PDF file so that the user can see the PDF document.

Which function can enable the MySQL server to call the PDF file? Should I insert a function to the table or what?

Comment: From mysql you can get the path of the file. And you can use server side language which ever you are using to get the file.

Comment: MySQL can't open files. Therefore, it can't "call" it. Use PHP to open the file, obtain the file path from MySQL. That's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the path of the file in the database and call it using PHP methode fileopen()

Comment: I have more quetionn, should i just put the path of the file on the row of the table like 'c:\something\something.pdf"